# Как сделать так чтобы цвет кнопки менялся допустим через 5 нажатий на нее?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
window.geometry('700x500')
window.title('Кликер')
points = 0

def check():
    global points
    b.place(x=random.randint(1,550),y=random.randint(1,350))
    points +=1
    label['text'] = points
    
b = Button(text='нажми меня', font=('Arial', 20), fg='black', command=check)
b.place(x=150,y=100)
label = Label(text = points, font=('Arial',15), fg='black')
label.place(x=10,y=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

что мешает сделать в лоб?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
window.geometry('700x500')
window.title('Кликер')
points = 0

bg_values = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'lime', 'orange']
bg_index = 0

def check():
    global points, bg_index
    b.place(x=random.randint(1, 550), y=random.randint(1, 350))
    points += 1
    label['text'] = points

    if points % 5 == 0:
        bg_index = 0 if bg_index == len(bg_values) else bg_index + 1
        b['fg'] = bg_values[bg_index]


b = Button(text='нажми меня', font=('Arial', 20), fg='black', command=check)
b.place(x=150, y=100)
label = Label(text=points, font=('Arial', 15), fg='black')
label.place(x=10, y=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Можно упростить `bg_index = (bg_index + 1) % len(bg_values)`

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не знаток в Питон. points это же счётчик да? Попробуй поставить условие на него